# NServiceBus custom error handling TransportMessage deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, error-handling, nservicebus

I'm using my CustomFaultManager to process failed messages, so I can handle them just before putting them in error queue.

in

```
void IManageMessageFailures.ProcessingAlwaysFailsForMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e)
{
```

I get TransportMessage and I have to get type from:

```
var header = message.Headers["NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes"];
var messageType = MessageTypes.Where(x => x.AssemblyQualifiedName != null 
                                && header.Contains(x.AssemblyQualifiedName)).ToList();
```

and then apply my custom logic to unzip message (because I'm zipping large msmq messages). Is it possible to get in this method a message which is just like original message which I have in `Handle` method?

**Why this bothers me?** For now I need to remember to apply changes in my custom error handler whenever I change serialization method or zipping method.

I would be happy if I could just cast TransportMessage to my custom message implementation just like:

```
var myMessage = message as MyCustomMessage;
```

Do you know guys if there is a way to do custom error handling in NServiceBus without doing manual deserialization?

I tried casting to my type of a message (as above), but it keeps giving me null as a result, because message is serialized in `Message` field in `TransportMessage`

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve in the custom error handling and what Version of NServiceBus you are using. I might be able to provide you a solution then. Btw. IManageMessageFailures always operates on TransportMessage level and therefore you are not operating on the logical message level (the actual payload of the message)

Comment: @DanielMarbach I'm using NServiceBus 4.5. I want to get message just before it's sent to error queue. I want to get it's content (casted as my custom message implementation) and do my magic with it. So far I need to deal with `TransportMessage`.

Comment: Is it an option for you to upgrade to 5.0? With the behavior pipeline this got much easier.

Comment: @DanielMarbach for now it's not an option. We've recently migrated to 4.5 and it was a real pain.

Comment: Have you looked at mutators? http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/message-mutators, btw. would you mind to reach me at daniel dot marbach at particular dot net and explain the pain you had when you migrated? Would be a good learning experience for us.

Answer (score 1):

We're also on an older version of NServiceBus (3.x).  So far, our solution is to have our message handler catch any exceptions, and then wrap them in a custom exception that contains the values that we need from the message. We then throw this exception for NServiceBus to handle.

In our `IManageMessageFailures.ProcessingAlwaysFailsForMessage` implementation, we invoke the appropriate error handler based on the the Exception type as well as the NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes values.

Hope this helps.